# Can you please help factor this polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

Can someone give me a step  by step tutorial on factoring this polynomial?
$a^3 + 6a^2 - ab^2 - 6b^2$

Answer (score 5):

$$\begin{align} a^3 + 6a^2 - ab^2 - 6b^2 & = a^2(a + 6) -(ab^2 + 6b^2) \\ \\ & = a^2(\color{blue}{a+6}) - b^2(\color{blue}{a + 6}) \\ \\ &=  \color{blue}{(a + 6)}(a^2 - b^2)\\ \\ &= \cdots \end{align}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Very nice. +1....

Answer (score 2):

First rearrange the terms:-

$a^3+6a^2-ab^2-6b^2=a^3-ab^2+6a^2-6b^2$

Next factor out $a$ from the first two terms, and $6$ from the last two terms:-

$a(a^2-b^2)+6(a^2-b^2)$

Now
$a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$

So you have

$a(a-b)(a+b)+6(a-b)(a+b)$

Can you take it from there?

Comment: I got it from here thanks!!!

Comment: Your welcome - glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$a^3+6a^2-ab^2-6b^2=a^3-ab^2+6(a^2-b^2)=a\underbrace{(a^2-b)^2}+6\underbrace{(a^2-b^2)}$$

I leave the rest for you to complete

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $ $ Easy factors arise if the  first and second half of the polynomial are linearly dependendent:

**Theorem** $\ \  f(x)= ax^3\!+bx^2\!+cx+d\, =\, (ax+b)(x^2+c/a)\ \ $ if $\ \ \color{#c00}{ad = bc},\ \ a\ne 0$

**Proof** $\ \ (ax\!+\!b)(x^2\!+c/a) = (ax\!+\!b)x^2 + (ax\!+\!\color{#c00}{b)c/a} = f(x)\ \, $ by $\,\ \color{#c00}{bc/a = d}$

Yours is the special case $\ f(x) = x^3\!+6\,x^2-b^2 x-6b^2,\,$ where $\ ad = 1(-6b^2) = 6(-b^2) = bc.\ $ Hence, by the theorem, $\ f(x) = (x+6)(x^2-b^2) = (x+6)(x-b)(x+b).$

**Remark** $ $ If linear algebra is known then, more intuitively, it is a criterion for linear dependence of $(a,b)$ and $(c,d),\,$ i.e. that the matrix they form has determinant $\,=ad-bc= 0.\,$ When so, by $\,a\ne 0,\,$ we obtain $\,cx+d\, =\, c/a\,(ax+b)\,$ yielding the factor $\,ax+b\,$ of $\,f(x),\,$ since its first half $= (ax+b)x^2$ also has a factor $\,ax+b.\,$  The same idea works more generally for testing for factors of higher degree polynomials by looking for linear dependence between the first and second half of the polynomial's terms.